# Как получить функцию из стека вызовов без использования debug.getinfo

Tags: lua

Нужно получить **ссылку на функцию** по номеру из стека вызовов. Есть вариант использовать debug.getinfo, но он всегда возвращает новую таблицу, что критично, т.к. участок кода в программе выполняется очень часто.

Comment: Давно не писал на lua, но могу попробовать ответить. Единственное ограничение — нужно задействовать будет C (для этой функции). Подойдёт?

Comment: Буду благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include "lua.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"

static int l_getfunction(lua_State *L) {
    lua_Debug ar;
    int level = luaL_checkinteger(L, 1);
    if (level < 0) luaL_error(L, "invalid stack level");
    if (lua_getstack(L, level, &ar) != 1) return 0; // слишком глубоко
    if (lua_getinfo(L, "f", &ar) == 0) luaL_error(L, "failed to get function");
    return 1;
}

int luaopen_getfunction(lua_State *L) {
    lua_pushcfunction(L, l_getfunction); // require вернёт нашу функцию
    return 1;
}
```

Тестировал на Lua 5.2.

Для корректной работы необходимо, чтобы библиотека загружалась через `require 'getfunction'`, иначе lua не найдёт функцию.

Репозиторий с CMake-файлом для сборки и проверки: https://github.com/v1993/lua-getfunction.

Использование:

```
getf = require 'getfunction'
getf(1) -- Текущая функция
assert(getf(0) == getf) -- Сама getf
getf(2) -- Тот, кто нас вызвал
getf(1000) -- 99%, что ничего
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.