# Ошибка при загрузке разделяемой библиотеки на Android "... is not accessible for the classloader-namespace"

Tags: android, c, lua, android-ndk

Возникла необходимость собрать динамическую библиотеку для Lua на андроид, но после сборки и попытки загрузить полученную библиотеку, получаю следующую ошибку:
error loading module 'getfunc' from file 'sdcard/lovegame/lib/getfunc_android.so':
dlopen failed: library "sdcard/lovegame/lib/getfunc_android.so" needed or dlopened by "/data/app/org.love2d.android-2/lib/arm/liblove.so" is not accessible for the namespace "classloader-namespace"

Код исходника "getfunction.c" (взят [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/868287/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-debug-getinfo)):

```
#include "lua.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
#include "lualib.h"

static int l_getfunc(lua_State *L) {
    lua_Debug ar;
    int level = luaL_checkinteger(L, 1);
    if (level < 0) luaL_error(L, "invalid stack level");
    if (lua_getstack(L, level, &ar) != 1) return 0;
    if (lua_getinfo(L, "f", &ar) == 0) luaL_error(L, "failed to get function");
    return 1;
}

int luaopen_getfunc(lua_State *L) {
    lua_pushcfunction(L, l_getfunc);
    return 1;
}
```

Содержимое "Application.mk":

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_ARM_MODE  := arm
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -Wall -D"l_getlocaledecpoint()='.'" -DLUA_ANSI
LOCAL_MODULE    := getfunc
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lua/src/getfunction.c
APP_ALLOW_MISSING_DEPS := true
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := C:/Users/admin/workspace/getfunc/jni/liblua.so
LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS := true
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Содержимое "Android.mk":

```
APP_ABI := x86_64
APP_PLATFORM := android-14
```

Для сборки использую android-ndk-r17b

Comment: Не уверен, что проблема в этом, но `arm/liblove.so` явно архитектуры arm, а в `Android.mk` библиотеки (моей, к слову) указана `x86_64`.

Comment: @val пробовал собирать и на armeabi-v7a, тот же результат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял, данная ошибка появляется из-за отсутствия доступа для приложения к вашей SD-карте.

Для начала, вручную добавьте библиотеку (корректной архитектуры!) в APK (рядом с нужной `liblove.so`) и протестируйте так. Если всё получится, включите библиотеку в процесс сборки всего приложения, чтобы гарантировать корректность линковки, обеспечить сборку для всех архитектур и автоматизировать включение в APK.

Альтернатива — отредактировать файл `public.libraries.txt`, находящийся в `/etc` или `/vendor/etc`.

Comment: Уже находил такой ответ на подобный вопрос. К сожалению, мне он не подходит, т.к. я не являюсь автором приложения, а лишь запускаю этим приложением lua-скрипты, для которых нужна эта динамическая библиотека. В моей ситуации она должна храниться вместе со скриптами, а не быть вручную заброшена в папку приложения.

Comment: @Handagotes Будете ли вы распространять этот скрипт публично? Если нет, то есть способ добавить исключение в систему для конкретной библиотеки.

Comment: Варианты с вмешательством в систему или изменением приложения меня не устраивают. Я надеялся на ответ, который поможет мне собрать открытую библиотеку, доступную для других библиотек.

Comment: @Handagotes Боюсь, это невозможно из-за системы безопасности андроида.

Comment: ладно, и на том спасибо.